# Using multiple USB cameras with Web RTC

Tags: camera, webrtc

I want to use multiple USB camera with Web RTC.

For ex)
https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=93443359

This application is web RTC sample.
I can connect to another machine, but I have to disconnect once to change the camera.

What I want to is,

1.Use two camera at the same time on the same screen.
2.(if 1 is not possible),I want to switch the camera without disconnecting current connection

Does anyone have information about how to use two camera on Web RTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call getUserMedia twice and change the camera input in between

Answer (score 4):

You can use **constraints** to specify which camera to use and you can have both of them displayed in one page as well. To specify which camera to use take a look at the following snippet (only works on Chrome 30+):

```
getUserMedia({
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      sourceId: webcamId,
      ...
    }
  }, 
  successCallback,
  failCallback);
```

The `webcamId` you can get by:

```
MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sources){
  var cams = _.filter(sources, function(e){ //only return video elements 
    return e.kind === 'video';
  });
  var camIds = _.map(cams, function (e) { // return only ids
    return e.id;
  });
});
```

In the snippet above I've used [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) methods `filter` and `map`.

More information on:

- WebRTC [video sources](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/)
- [constraints](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/constraints/)

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) are available in modern browser.

Comment: true. i mean where getUserMedia is available they should work as well. I'm just used to using underscore